# If 'fsck' has to run and do some repair, shouldn't a 'Timeshift' restore be run?

Tags: 22.04, fsck, timeshift

My reason for asking is that fsck probably has to make assumptions which may not be correct and hide a lingering problem.  Running a Restore is more likely to result in a stable system?

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: 2 different things. The fsck (File System Consistency Check) Linux utility checks filesystems for errors or outstanding issues. The tool is used to fix potential errors and generate reports. Timeshift is to restore your system to a restorepoint you made before with it.

Comment: If you have a damaged filesystem (which is what `fsck` repairs), you should avoid writing anything to the disk and repair the filesystem first. Then if you find out that some data got lost, you may optionally restore from backup.